# scale animation from scroll sub view (Image view ) to UIwindow and zoom

Tags: iphone, ios

May be this Question may be duplicate but i really need your help..

[image: Grid Image]

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
NewFeedDetailVC *nextViewController = [[NewFeedDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewFeedDetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
nextViewController.originRect = imgFrame;
nextViewController.currentscrolloffset=aStylizedView.contentOffset.y;
[window addSubview:nextViewController.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     nextViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, ScreenHeight-20);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

above is demo code i have tried to make zoom animation before push ..

imgFrame is image on which user will tap 
When user click right top orange (four square) button ,and code as below

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame=self.originRect;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [test removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

view should be pop out with zoom in animation to there parent frame but i am not able to perform smooth transition and image suppose to be same as parent frame and just black view is scaling to original frame, and another issue is you can observe animation is not clipping out in navigation control even if Its frame is clipping in original scroll view.

Thanks

[image: After push to next view controller]
[image: While poping to grid image view part-1]
[image: To next grid image view]